# How to get selected value in dropdown in asp.net core 2.2?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to get the selected value in the dropdown when getting the data from database.

I have tried using:

```
<option value="" style="font-size:medium; font-weight:bold; ">
    Select Action
</option>
<option value="Sent To Dhoobi" 
  selected="@(item.Suit_Status == "Sent To Dhoobi" ? "selected" : "")">
    Sent To Dhoobi
</option>
<option value="Sent For Cutting" 
  selected="@(item.Suit_Status == "Sent For Cutting" ? "selected" : "")">
    Sent For Cutting
</option>
<option value="In Rack" 
  selected="@(item.Suit_Status == "In Rack" ? "selected" : null)">
    In Rack
</option>
<option value="Delivered" 
  selected="@(item.Suit_Status == "Delivered" ? "selected" : null)">
    Delivered
</option>
```

I want to get the selected value in the dropdown but cannot get the value.

Comment: Any help will be appreciated! Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have a select element around the options?

Answer (score 2):

Can you change the way you build that dropdown? You can define a property for the selected suit status and a list of available suit statuses in the *view model*, and build the dropdown on the *view* with *tag helpers*.

#### View model

```cs
// I just make up the name
public class UpdateSuitViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Status")]
    public string SelectedSuitStatus { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<string> AvailableSuitStatuses { get; set; }
}
```

#### Controller

In the *controller*, you can build the view model with the data from the database:

```cs
public IActionResult Edit()
{
    // Get the statues from the database
    var suitStatuses = ...    

    var vm = new UpdateSuitViewModel
    {
        AvailableSuitStatuses = suitStatuses
    };

    return View(vm);
}
```

#### View

```
@model UpdateSuitViewModel

<form>
    <select class="form-control"
        asp-for="SelectedSuitStatus"
        asp-items="new SelectList(Model.AvailableSuitStatuses)">
        <option value="">Select Action</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

The *tag helper* for the dropdown from *ASP.NET CORE* will help you build the dropdown with the name `SelectedSuitStatus` and dropdown options from `AvailableSuitStatuses`;

When you post the form back, the view model `SelectedSuitStatus` will contain the selected dropdown option value!